# Seam 3 in a nutshell?

Tags: jsf, seam, cdi

As a JSF 2/PrimeFaces developer I've had a look at Seam 3 as something that
could be useful in my project. So far the @RenderScoped functionality looks
interesting as a replacement for view scope and flash/page parameters, and
the catch module could be useful for more centralised exception handling. Are
there any other big ticket items in there that haven't immediately come to
my notice? I'm not quite convinced that it's worth investing in the time to
carry out a migration (much as I'm not similarly convinced about moving to
CDI from JSF managed bean annotations).

I hadn't exactly come across any literature that I would describe as a
summary.

Thanks,
O/S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will have to read the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/) for yourself, but this is what I like about Seam 3 and what I am using:

- Seam Solder (logger Injection, various annotations like @Veto, @Requires, resource-injection)
- Seam I18N / Seam Faces (View Scopes, Message builder integration, automatic message conversion, handling & propagation of locales)
- Seam Validation (bridging to Hibernate Validator which allows to use method-level validation (@AutoValidate of parameters / return values)
- Seam Catch (you named it already)
- Seam Mail (easy adoption of mailing functionality)
- Seam Config (XML config of everything, extremely useful for Catch / Mail / etc)

Depending of the usecase, Seam Security and Seam Persistence might be just what you were looking for, same is true for Seam Rest.

There are various "Seam Modul spotlights" hiding at [in.relation.to](http://in.relation.to) that are worth checking out...

Comment: I've been through the docs, it's helpful to hear some opinions,

Answer (score 0):

I've tried so far security and i18n modules and they are great. Seam 3 is a really nice stuff to extend your toolbox. Highly recommended!

Comment: have you tried pageflow feature in seam3 ?? I'm trying but its not similar to seam2 . can you help ??